# how facebook notifications work?

Tags: jquery, ajax, facebook

I want to understand how facebook notifications work. When someone like your posts, comments, send message, etc, facebook sends a notification as soon as the event done. I want to know if there is any server side script or events fired when users hit like button, posts, send messages, etc.
I need to know how to implement something like that using jquery and php to use on my wbsite.

Comment: Are you asking because you want to hook into that event? i.e. you want to be notified when these events happen as well?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's done using *push* events: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology